# How can I get my Xamarin.Forms application to redraw when the user hides the Android navigation bar on Samsung S9

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms application, which fails to redraw, when the user hides the navigation bar on Samsung S9 (and probably S8 as well). All I get is an empty white space where the navigation bar used to be.

The attached images, showing the bottom of the screen, demonstrate what I see before and after hiding the navigation bar.

Navigation bar visible:

[image: Navigation bar visible]

Navigation bar hidden:

[image: Navigation bar hidden]

Is there any way for my application to respond and redraw the screen to utilise the extra space left by the navigation bar? Note that the splash screen fills the whole display and does not leave empty space at the bottom.

Comment: Show your code, so we can look at and help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The application in question is quite large and as I had no clue as to where the problem lay I didn't know what to show here. However, after further debugging, I found the problem and I will post my solution here in case someone else has similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the application I was working on was using code based on [Michael Dimoudis's solution](http://michaeldimoudis.com/blog/2015/11/14/taming-the-keyboard-in-native-app-development-using-xamarin-forms) to "tame" the keyboard on Android.

This solution selectively modifies the height of the root view as the soft keyboard appears and disappears. It turns out that it was too selective for my needs and I modified the code to always update the height if the available height changes.

For others using Michael's solution and/or interested in my modifications, I changed the method **PossiblyResizeChildOfContent** to read:

```
    private void PossiblyResizeChildOfContent()
    {
        var usableHeightNow = this.ComputeUsableHeight();
        if (usableHeightNow != this.usableHeightPrevious)
        {
            this.frameLayoutParams.Height = usableHeightNow;
            this.mChildOfContent.RequestLayout();
            this.usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone with similar issues.